# Displaying comments and likes for ended broadcasted live stream video

Tags: android, live-streaming

I have successfully integrated live stream functionality using Wowza in my Android application.

In which we can broadcast a live stream and during broadcasting viewer can comment and like for ongoing live stream. We are storing such comments and likes in our backend side.

Later any user can view/play the stored video.

Now, We have to display all the comments and likes during playing the stored or ended video. It should show same as it was during live broadcasting.

How can we achieve such functionality ?

Do we need to manage it with the video duration timestamp ?

Is there any other option or a way available to do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's (at least) two ways you can achieve this.

The first is to store a timestamp relative to the start of the recording along with the comment or the like in your database. So if your recording start point counts as 00:00:00 and 2 minutes in the stream someone made a comment, then you store something like 
`{"comment":"viewer comment", "timestamp":"00:02:00" }`.

Of course there are 100s of ways to store data (maybe you use SQL; maybe you write timestamp as seconds instead of HH:mm:ss), but you get the point.

Then, at playback you load all the timestamps and use the player's "ontimeupdate" event to check if there's a corresponding timestamp in your database (tip: load these upfront so your check isn't delayed). So if the player is 2 minutes out in playback it'll see there's a match with the timestamp of the comment you stored previously, and you can show the comment.

The other option is to use ID3 tags in the stream. This requires customization of your Wowza server by means of a module. You can inject timed metadata into the stream using a custom HTTP provider and convert that to ID3 event tags using a custom module.

You will then need to configure the player to listen for ID3 events and react accordingly. NB! When you start the recording of your stream, make sure that you record the data track (this is a separate option)

For more information on this last option; see

- https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-use-timed-metadata-in-wowza-live-streaming-workflows
- https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-inject-cue-points-or-metadata
- https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-convert-ontextdata-events-in-a-live-or-vod-stream-to-timed-events-id3-tags-in-an-apple-hls-stream
- https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-listen-for-metadata-and-trigger-an-action-with-the-wowza-player-javascript-api